# Visual C++ relational operator overloading const correctness (with std::sort)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, const-correctness

In the example code below, the overloaded operator< was not const qualified, and it compiles under Visual C++ (all versions up to 2013 Preview), but under Clang, it throws an error - note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const Entry', but method is not marked const bool operator<( const Entry& other ).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct Entry
{
    unsigned int age;
    bool operator<( const Entry& other ) // !!! no const qualification here !!!
    {
        return age < other.age;
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<Entry> entries;
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < 100; ++i )
    {
        Entry entry;
        entry.age = i;
        entries.push_back( entry );
    }
    // Sort by age
    std::sort( entries.begin(), entries.end() );
    return 0;
}
```

Is Visual C++ not standard conforming in enforcing the const-correctness of the comparison/relational operators? Or this is something to do with std::sort?

Comment: Probably a `std::sort` implementation issue: clang is comparing the objects in a `const` context, while VC++ is not.  As a general rule, when clang and VC++ disagree, it is because VC++s implementation has an error.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ standard states that it is assumed that no non-constant function will be applied via the dereferenced iterators, first by stating it in terms of the `Compare` functor that can be passed to `sort`:

> `Compare` is a function object type (20.8). The return value of the function call operation applied to an object
>   of type `Compare`, when contextually converted to bool (4), yields true if the first argument of the call is
>   less than the second, and false otherwise. `Compare` `comp` is used throughout for algorithms assuming an
>   ordering relation. **It is assumed that `comp` will not apply any non-constant function through the dereferenced
>   iterator**.

(emphasis mine)

and then, by stating the relation between `Compare` and `operator<`:

> For all algorithms that take `Compare`, there is a version that uses `operator<` instead. That is, `comp(*i,
>   *j) != false` defaults to `*i < *j != false`. For algorithms other than those described in 25.4.3 to work
>   correctly, `comp` has to induce a strict weak ordering on the values.

Both quotes from . From **25.4 Sorting and related operations**.

So, although it is not explicitly stated that a member `operator<` has to be `const`, the assumption that it is means it must be. It would not make sense to place restrictions on `comp` and not on `operator<`.

I would say Visual C++ is at fault here since it allows for non-const functions to be called on the dereferenced iterators.